# Intrusion Detection System (IDS)

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, anomaly-detection

I am new to anomaly intrusion detection system. I was reading the [service specific anomaly detection for network intrusion detection](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/770b/ae9ed688a84cfd2705a4ae4a11f5c9701f03.pdf) but I could not understand section ***3.2.3 payload Distribution***, page 5. To better understand the author I tried to do the calculations by hand but I am lost. I have included a sample of my calculations.

- How do we calculate the *payload distribution* if we have many *character distribution* (one *character distribution* for each request in the training set)?
- How do we calculate the segments for the *payload distribution*?
- Given a new request how do we calculate its anomaly score?

[image: My calculations]